# Comparing topologies and metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$, $C([0,1])$, with 3 different metrics, $d_1$,$d_2$ and $d_\infty$, and the topologies induced by those metrics, $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$, $\tau_\infty$. I must to prove that $\tau_2$ is coarser than $\tau_\infty$.

I do not give the definition of every metric, because, before trying to solve this question I want to understand the relationship between the equivalence of metrics and comparing topologies. I mean, if $d \le \rho$, for any metrics $d$, $\rho$, what does this tell me about: comparing open balls with those metrics, comparing open sets in their respective topologies.

My teacher told me that, if $d \le \rho$ then $B_\rho(x, r) \subseteq B_d(x, \varepsilon)$ and $\tau_d \preceq \tau_\rho$. But this is not clear to me at all, neither in the matter of formal logic nor in intuition of what that says to me.

I hope I was clear and I would really appreciate it if you could help me to understand this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to be clear what $d \le \rho$ and $\tau_1 \preceq \tau_2$ mean. From what your teacher says, $d \le \rho$ must mean that $d(x, y) \le \rho(x, y)$ for every $x$ and $y$ and $\tau_1 \preceq \tau_2$ means that every $\tau_1$-open set is also $\tau_2$-open (i.e., $\tau_1$ is coarser than (or equal to) $\tau_2$.

If $d \le \rho$ in the above sense, then $B_\rho(x, \epsilon) \subseteq B_d(x, \epsilon)$ for every $x$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Why? Answer: Because $y \in B_\rho(x, \epsilon)$ implies that $\rho(y, x) < \epsilon$, which (because $d \le \rho$) implies that $d(y, x) < \epsilon$ implying that $y \in B_d(x, \epsilon)$.

But if $B_\rho(x, \epsilon) \subseteq B_d(x, \epsilon)$ for every $x$ and $\epsilon > 0$ we must have $\tau_d \preceq \tau_\rho$. Why? Answer: if $A$ is $\tau_d$-open, then for every $x \in A$, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_d(x, \epsilon) \subseteq A$, but then, because $B_\rho(x, \epsilon) \subseteq B_d(x, \epsilon)$, we have that $B_\rho(x, \epsilon) \subseteq A$. So for every point $x$ of $A$ there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_\rho(x, \epsilon) \subseteq A$. So $A$ is $\tau_\rho$-open. We have shown that every $\tau_d$-open set is also $\tau_\rho$-open, so $\tau_d\preceq \tau_\rho$.

Comment: Much clearer! You are using the same radius $\epsilon$ for the open balls; is it still true for different radii, $\epsilon, r \gt 0$? Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected what must be a typo without mentioning it. It is not possible for every open $\rho$-ball to be contained in every open $d$-ball except in the trivial case when the space has only one point. If there are two points $x \neq y$, you can always find a $\rho$-ball around $x$ that includes $y$ (say the one with radius $r = 2\rho(x, y)$) and a $d$-ball around $x$ that does not contain $y$ (say the one with radius $\epsilon = d(x, y)/2$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a set and endow it with two topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, then $\tau_2$ is coarser then $\tau_1$ iff the identity map
$$I : (X,\tau_1) \longrightarrow (X,\tau_2) $$ is continuous. (Can you see why?)

Since you are working with metric spaces a function is continuous iff it's sequentially continuous, then if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the metrics generating topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ respectively with $d_2\leq d_1$, for any $x\in X$ take a sequence $x_n$ converging to $x$ in the $d_1$ metric, you get

$d_2(x,x_n)=d_2(I(x),I(x_n))\leq d_1(x,x_n)\longrightarrow 0$, so the identity map is continuous therefore $\tau_2$ is weaker then $\tau_1$